# О типах библиотек debug, release, debug dll, release dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, библиотеки

Хочу основательно разобраться в вопросе о типах библиотек и параметрах /MT (статическая), /MD (dll), /MTd (статическая дебаг) и /MDd (дебаг dll). То, чем отличается статическая библиотека от DLL, я знаю. Важно другое.

Допустим, есть фреймворк для тестирования, в состав которого входит библиотека. И есть проект, в котором нужны юнит-тесты. Проект может быть Debug и Release. Какие подводные камни возникают при подключении к такому проекту библиотеки для тестирования?

Допустим, проект Debug. Тогда библиотека для тестирования тоже должна быть собрана в дебаге? Если проект Release, то библиотека должна быть собрана как Release? И если тип сборки библиотеки отличается от типа сборки проекта, сборка проекта зафейлится на этапе линковки из-за неразрешенных символов?

Имеет ли значение, как собирать библиотеку: как статическую или динамическую?

Answer (score 1):

Смешивание разных версий стандартной библиотеки С++ в программе, в целом, поддерживается. Отладочная и релизная версии DLL имеют разное имя, например ucrtbased.dll и ucrtbase.dll, поэтому они могут независимо существовать в одном процессе.

Проблемы появляются, когда объекты, созданные в одной версии библиотеки, передаются в код, использующий другую версию: внутренняя структура дескрипторов файлов и других объектов может быть разной. При использовании объекта в другой версии библиотеки может возникнуть ошибка или непредсказуемое поведение.

Если в DLL используется статическая стандартная библиотека, для нее создается независимый "экземпляр" со своим состоянием, существующий параллельно экземпляру основной программы. Передача объектов из одного экземпляра в другой также может привести к ошибкам (даже если они одной версии). Статическое связывание имеет и другие проблемы: увеличение размера бинарников, невозможность использования обновлений безопасности и т.п. Поэтому, статическое связывание со стандартной библиотекой для DLL не рекомендуется.

Подробнее: [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)